# Terminal colour changing on VSC for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I want to change the color of my terminal on VSC. However, after following the steps it shows me this specific error: `End of file expected`

Can anyone help?

[image: screenshot of settings]

Comment: The  '{' is missing before "workbench.colorCustomizations" ;-):

{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.background": "#00AA00"
  }
}

Comment: JSON files always need to start and end with curly braces. `{...json...}`

Comment: What is the source of the "steps" are you following? Is this the whole settings file?

Comment: I just found a sample code on the internet and the pasted it into the color settings edit @martineau

Answer (score 0):

Your `settings.json` is not a valid json it has missing curly braces it should be something like this.

```json
{
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/mahesh/Documents/flutter",

    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "comments": "#507046",
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "list.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#273d97",
        "list.inactiveSelectionForeground": "#ffffff",
        "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#474d64",
        "list.activeSelectionForeground": "#ffffff",
        "terminal.ansiBlack": "#ff0000",
        "terminal.ansiRed": "#ff0000",
        "terminal.foreground": "#273d97",
        "terminal.ansiGreen": "#00ff00",
    }
}
```

Comment: It is definitely okay to post this answer even though it is answered in the comments, but I think it would be nice if you acknowledged those prior correct statements.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand which statements are you referring to?

Comment: Yes, I agree! But I didn't intend to repeat their same answer, I just didn't like leaving the question unanswered.

Comment: Sure thanks for the feedback, I will do that next time in such scenarios :)